Unreal Engine Crashing on macOS When Applying SetWindowMode
I’m working on an Unreal Engine project, and I’m encountering an issue where my application crashes or becomes unresponsive on macOS when applying Fullscreen or Windowed mode to the selected monitor.
I have a function, ApplyFullscreenToMonitor(), that applies fullscreen mode to a selected monitor.
It first retrieves the display metrics and then tries to move and resize the window based on the monitor’s resolution and position. The function works fine on Windows, but on macOS, the app freezes or becomes unresponsive.
Here’s the code:
void UEtrResolutionSetting::ApplyFullscreenToMonitor()
{
    // Get game user settings
    UGameUserSettings* GameUserSettings = GEngine->GetGameUserSettings();
    if (GameUserSettings)
    {
        FDisplayMetrics displayMetrics;
        FSlateApplication::Get().GetDisplayMetrics(displayMetrics);
        const int32 num = displayMetrics.MonitorInfo.Num();
        int32 chosenIndex = -1;
        int32 primaryIndex = 0;
        for (int32 i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            FMonitorInfo& info = displayMetrics.MonitorInfo[i];
            if (info.Name == SelectedMonitor.Name)
            {
                chosenIndex = i;
                break;
            }
            if (info.bIsPrimary) { primaryIndex = i; }
        }
        int32 finalIndex = (chosenIndex < 0) ? primaryIndex : chosenIndex;
        if (chosenIndex < 0 && !SelectedMonitor.Name.IsEmpty())
        {
            // NOTE: Log something here
        }
        const FMonitorInfo& info = displayMetrics.MonitorInfo[finalIndex];
        const FIntPoint resolution = GameUserSettings->GetScreenResolution();
        if (resolution.X > info.NativeWidth || resolution.Y > info.NativeHeight)
        {
            GameUserSettings->SetScreenResolution({ info.NativeWidth, info.NativeHeight });
        }
        GameUserSettings->SetWindowPosition(info.WorkArea.Left, info.WorkArea.Top);
        // Move the window to the selected monitor and resize
        if (GEngine && GEngine->GameViewport && GEngine->GameViewport->GetWindow())
        {
            TSharedPtr<SWindow> window = GEngine->GameViewport->GetWindow();
            EWindowMode::Type const WindowMode = GEngine->GetGameUserSettings()->GetFullscreenMode();
            window->MoveWindowTo(GameUserSettings->GetWindowPosition());
            window->Resize(GameUserSettings->GetScreenResolution());
            window->SetWindowMode(WindowMode);
            GameUserSettings->SetFullscreenMode(WindowMode);
            GameUserSettings->ApplyResolutionSettings(false);
        }
        else
        {
            mDelegateHandleViewportCreated = UGameViewportClient::OnViewportCreated().AddUObject(
                this, &UEtrResolutionSetting::ApplyFullscreenToMonitor);
        }
        if (mDelegateHandleViewportCreated.IsValid())
        {
            UGameViewportClient::OnViewportCreated().Remove(mDelegateHandleViewportCreated);
            mDelegateHandleViewportCreated.Reset();
        }
        // Log successful fullscreen change on the specific monitor
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Game switched to fullscreen on monitor: %s with resolution %dx%d"), *SelectedMonitor.Name, resolution.X, resolution.Y);
    }
    else
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Error, TEXT("Failed to get GameUserSettings"));
    }
}

The game window gets crashed, I can move the mouse but I can't click anywhere and I had to force quit the game.


Given the relationship betwen Apple and Epic, and my own anecdotal experience of the EGS (an Unreal app from the people that should know) never working properly on my Macbook Pro, I'd like to put the idea out there that Unreal stuff on a Mac is something neither company seems very interested in. Unless things have changed in the last couple years. I don't try EGS often because it's such a pain to fully uninstall when the install itself is broken.

It's been many days, i am stuck with this, and not a ray of hope.
